# Redirection issue with URL parameter with ADAL.js and UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, adal.js

I configured the state which contains url with url parameters like this: `url:route/:id1/:id2:id3` with ADAL js. When I hit url with `route/1/2/3`, after login, I am redirected to `route/:id1/:id2/:id3?id1=1&id2=2&id3=3` instead of  `route/1/2/3`.

I investigated further and in adal-angular.js file, we are setting browser url with `$location.url().search(jsonParameters)` where `jsonParameters` is json object with value `{id1:1, id2:2, id3:3}` which is causing the url malformation.

Can you guys point me in correct direction on how to solve this issue and redirect to proper url?

**Edit: Adding code sample**

I have configured the AAD route as specified below:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('State1', {
            templateUrl: getViewUrl('viewUrl'),
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'home',
            url: '/route/:id1/:id2/:id3',
            requireADLogin: true
        })
```

I am initializing the adal sevice provider in following way:

```
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    var endpoints = {}
    endpoints[EnvironmentConfig.url1] = EnvironmentConfig.url1;
    endpoints[EnvironmentConfig.url2] = EnvironmentConfig.url2;

    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
              {
                  instance: EnvironmentConfig.aadUrl,                           // 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
                  tenant: EnvironmentConfig.tenant,                             // 'microsoft.onmicrosoft.com',
                  clientId: EnvironmentConfig.clientId,                         
                  endpoints: endpoints,
                  loginResource: EnvironmentConfig.breServiceADUrl              
                  //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
              }, $httpProvider);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am failed to reproduce this issue. How did you set the browser URL in the adal-angular.js?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT,  have configured my web application to use Azure AD login through adal-angular.js. So I have defined this url with state provider along with requireADLogin:true.

Comment: I also add the `requireADLogin: true` via the `$routeProvider` but still not able to reproduce this issue. Did you mix the ui-router and ngRoute? It is helpful if you can provide a code sample to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT, I have added the sample state declaration and initialization of adal service provider for reference. I am using 1.0.10 version of ADAL.js.

Comment: Did the code in the post work for you?

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT, I found the issue in adal.angular.js and fixed it. I am planning to construct the answer with snippet today with repro and fix.

Comment: Have you completed the answer? It is helpful for others who have the same issue if you can share the answer.

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT, sorry for the delay. I have modified your code and posted the code which reproduces the issue. You can just copy the url and paste it in incognito to repro the issue. Please let me know if this is known bug in adal-angular.

Comment: Hi @FeiXue-MSFT, have you got time to take a look at my code?

Comment: Thanks for the detail code for this issue. It seems this issue was fixed by the version `1.0.12` of ADAL from [#345](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/345). I suggest that you upgrade the ADAL to the latest version  `1.0.13` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the source code for adal-angular.js and found out that there is an issue when redirecting to the link with url parameters. I have modified code by @Fei Xue little bit to reproduce the scenario.

```html
<!-- inject:css -->
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- bower:js -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.10/js/adal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.10/js/adal-angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>


<!-- endinject -->



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
       <base href="/">


</head>
<body>

    <div >
        <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a ui-sref="hello({id1:1,id2:2,id3:1})" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello/1/2/3" ui-sref-active="active">Hello2</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a></li>
                <li ng-show="userInfo.isAuthenticated"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="" ng-hide="userInfo.isAuthenticated" ng-click="login()">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ui-view></ui-view>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

    
<script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['AdalAngular', 'ui.router'])
.config(['$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$stateProvider','$locationProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function ($httpProvider, adalProvider, $stateProvider,$locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); 
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    adalProvider.init(
       {
           instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
           tenant: 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com',
           clientId: '<clientId>',
       },
       $httpProvider
       );


        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";



    var helloState = {
        name: 'hello',
        url: '/hello/:id1/:id2/:id3',
        template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // alert('kiran');
        },
        requireADLogin: true
    }

    var aboutState = {
        name: 'about',
        url: '/about',
        template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
    }

    var homeState={
        name:'home',
        url:'/',
        controller:function(){
            
        },
        requireADLogin:true
    }

    $stateProvider.state(homeState);
    $stateProvider.state(helloState);
    $stateProvider.state(aboutState);


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}])
    myApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'adalAuthenticationService', '$location','$stateParams','$rootScope','$timeout',  function ($scope, $http, adalService, $location, $stateParams,$rootScope,$timeout) {
        $scope.double = function (value) { return value * 2; };

        $scope.login = function () {
            adalService.login();
        };
        $scope.logout = function () {
            adalService.logOut();
        };

        /*Fix for adal issue*/
    //     $rootScope.$on("adal:loginSuccess", function (e) {
  //              console.log('loginSuccess');
//
      //          $timeout(function () {
    //                var startPageURL = sessionStorage['adal.start.page'];
  //                  var stateParamsString = sessionStorage['adal.start.page.params'];
//
  //                  var stateParamsJson = stateParamsString ? JSON.parse(stateParamsString) : {};
//
                    //var matchedState = _.find($state.get(),
                  //      function (state) {
                //            return state.url == startPageURL;
             ///           });
           //         if (matchedState) {
         //               $state.go(matchedState.name, stateParamsJson, { reload: true });
       //             }
     //           }, 2);

      //      });
    }]);



</script>
```

I have added fix also. Adal-angular uses location.search method to replace the redirected url after successful login. But search method converts stored json object to query parameters which is causing the issue.

You can run below code as is to repro the issue. In incognito browser if we try to go to `http://localhost:8080/hello/1/2/3` and it will redirect us to `http://localhost:8080/#/hello/:id1/:id2/:id3?id1=1&id2=2&id3=1` which is wrong.

I have commented the fix for this issue. After uncommenting the code and it will work as expected and it will correctly redirect us to `http://localhost:8080/hello/1/2/3`

Answer (score 0):

The code I tested seems no different with yours, I post the code for your reference. Hope it is helpful:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.10/js/adal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.10/js/adal-angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a ui-sref="hello({id1:1,id2:2,id3:1})" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hello/1/2/3" ui-sref-active="active">Hello2</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a></li>
                <li ng-show="userInfo.isAuthenticated"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="" ng-hide="userInfo.isAuthenticated" ng-click="login()">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ui-view></ui-view>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['AdalAngular', 'ui.router', 'ngRoute'])
.config(['$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', '$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($httpProvider, adalProvider, $stateProvider, $routeProvider) {

    var endpoints = {
        "https://localhost:44327/": "https://adfei.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoAPI",
    };

    adalProvider.init(
       {
           instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
           tenant: 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com',
           clientId: '{clientId}',
           extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
           endpoints: endpoints,
       },
       $httpProvider
       );

    var helloState = {
        name: 'hello',
        url: '/hello/:id1/:id2/:id3',
        template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {

        },
        requireADLogin: true
    }

    var aboutState = {
        name: 'about',
        url: '/about',
        template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
    }

    $stateProvider.state(helloState);
    $stateProvider.state(aboutState);

    $routeProvider.
     when("/hello/:id1/:id2/:id3", {
         controller: "homeCtrl",
         templateUrl:  '<h3>hello world!-ngRoute</h3>',
         requireADLogin: true
     });
}])
    myApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'adalAuthenticationService', '$location',  function ($scope, $http, adalService, $location, $stateParams) {
        $scope.double = function (value) { return value * 2; };

        $scope.login = function () {
            adalService.login();
        };
        $scope.logout = function () {
            adalService.logOut();
        };

       
    }]);



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To test the code, first click the login and than you can switch the view by click the **Hello** and **About** hyperlink.

### Update

It seems this issue was fixed by the version `1.0.12` of ADAL from [#345](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/345). I suggest that you upgrade the ADAL to the latest version 1.0.13 to fix this issue.